# css positioning far right - with minimum width

Tags: css, positioning

I am a mostly skilled server-end developer, and am creating an ambitious website project - all by myself. I know c#, MVC, T-SQL, LINQ, and ASP.NET pretty well. Obviously, since I'm working by myself, I have knowledge in design too. I'm obviously good with html (who isn't?). And I absolutely love jQuery! The thing is, I'm decent in my understanding of css, but css is my least knowledgeable trait. I understand programming, I also am good in design, not just because I have a decent level of knowledge in css (and jQuery) - but also because I just know what looks good (I can draw and paint on real paper too).

The thing is, I know I can probably do this with jQuery code, but I was wondering if this could also be done with css alone. On my main design (Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) - I made the body to have a "min-width: (my value);" attribute, which, obviously isn't supported with older browsers, so I also included a transparent image of a default width of 1px that I set to stretch to my desired width also - it works in controlling the width of the page (to the minimum I desired). But - I have a site header div which resides at the top of the page. I have a part of that header div with elements positioned on the far right - which is nice when the browser is on a device that is large enough and the browser is in decent size, but once the browser is set to a size less than my desired minimum width, then the scroll bar shows up, and I can move it around as expected. But, the elements in that header div do not stay to the far right in conjunction with my minimum width - but stay on the right of the current window size instead. I have the main div holding the elements itself set to be in fixed position, I tried making those elements relative with no success. I tried a few ideas, the problem still persists.

So, as I said, I am well aware of concepts using jQuery that can do what I have previously described I desire in these regards, but, as I also said, I know a decent amount of css, but am the least close to an "expert" in css than anything else I know. I just have a strong suspicion what I desire here can be done with css and css alone (also, it would be nice to have it compatible with most browsers, or at the least most browsers made after the year 2008).

Can someone please give me some good information in these regards?

Comment: If you could provide us a sample of the code in a JSFiddle or JSBin, that would be fantastic! Otherwise, it sounds like you just need a min-width:400px; or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered asking this question.

I actually found a way to go about doing what I wrote I desired here through some experimentation that eventually got me to where I needed to be. What I did was instead of using relative positioning - which I thought was the proper way of doing this, I used absolute positioning inside the absolute positioned top header div. I didn't think this would be the solution at the time of asking the question, I assumed setting something as absolute positon - even inside something that is already absolute positioned - would put it in a new context of absolute positioning like any absolute positioned element inside the body tag. What I discovered was if I put an absolute positioned element inside another absolute positioned element - the context of the absolute positioning was based on the original absolute positioned element - so top (or left for that matter) 0px wasn't 0px from the context of the body (the very top of the page) - but - 0px from the element that the element is inside of. I think that's a pretty explanation of it, so I'll end explaining it here.

I'm sure there's plenty of people that know css much more than I do, and think this issue I had here is so basic, but, I did ask the question, and I might as well answer it based upon the solution I used. I could've posted an example on jsfiddle like asked for in a comment, but I thought my explanation was good enough, and since no one offered an answer based on my question alone, I decided to try to address the issue with experimentation, which I had success with.